# Como conectar externamente a Soket.io

Tags: nodejs, socket, socket.io, websocket

Estoy intentando realizar una aplicación que reciba notificaciones desde una URL para pasarles en tiempo real a los usuarios conectados a la aplicacion pero no esta funcionando, tengo esto en mi servidor NODE:

```
var express = require('express');
const { Server } = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

//app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.status(200).send("Hola mundo!");
});

io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log('Usuario Conectado');
    io.sockets.emit('prueba');
});   

server.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('Servidor corriendo');
});
```

y esto en mi php:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js',{'forceNew':true});
</script>
<script>
//ESCUCHO CUANDO SE ENVIAN LOS USUARIOS
socket.on('prueba', prueba);

function prueba(){
    alert ('hola');
}
</script>
```

Cuando me conecto a mi archivo php el servidor si lo detecta porque imprime 'Usuario Conectado', pero nada mas, el alert en el navegador no funciona. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias

Comment: Yo creo que es así: `io.on('connection',function(socket){
socket.on('prueba', (msg) => {
    io.emit('prueba', msg);
  });
});` aunque no lo puse como respuesta, porque la verdad no lo he probado.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @abrahamhs, no a funcionado lo que comentas. Saludos!